# How to convert "Number stored as text" to "Number" in .xls using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python code to analyse the student result in .xls format. The marks of students are formatted as "Numbers stored as text". 
["Number stored as text warning/ error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kbx5.png)
I have tried to read and assess these marks using xlrd, xlwt etc but failed.
Using VBS i am able to convert  "Numbers stored as text" to "Number" with below code:

```
Set Rng = objWorkbook.Worksheets(resultsheetname).Range(objWorkbook.Worksheets(resultsheetname).cells(8,4),objWorkbook.Worksheets(resultsheetname).cells(RowsCount-4,25))
For Each c In Rng
With Rng
If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
    If Not c = "AB " Then 
      If Not c= "-- " Then
        If Not c= "XX " Then
            If Not c= "**" then
                       c.Value = c.Value/1
                End if
            End if
        End if
    End If 
End If
End With
```

The python code i expect to work:

```
for cell in sheet1.col(3):
    #cell.value = cell.value
    #worksheet.write(0, 0, datetime.datetime.now(), style)
    if cell.value == 1:
        sem1 = sem1+1
        print(cell.value)
        #print(sheet1.row_values(cell))
    elif cell.value == 2 :
        sem2 = sem2+1
    elif cell.value == 3 :
        sem3 = sem3+1
    elif cell.value == 4 :
        sem4 = sem4+1
    elif cell.value == 5 :
        sem5 = sem5+1
    elif cell.value == 6 :
        sem6 = sem6+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need convert type

```python
for cell in sheet1.col(3):
    value = int(cell.value) # <-- to convert type
    #worksheet.write(0, 0, datetime.datetime.now(), style)
    if value == 1:
        sem1 = sem1+1
        print(cell.value)
        #print(sheet1.row_values(cell))
    elif value == 2 :
        sem2 = sem2+1
    elif value == 3 :
        sem3 = sem3+1
    elif value == 4 :
        sem4 = sem4+1
    elif value == 5 :
        sem5 = sem5+1
    elif value == 6 :
        sem6 = sem6+1
```

Maybe, need use a dict or list for the `sem` and shortly expression?

```python
# create dictionary sem = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}
sem = {x: 0 for x in range(1,7)}

for cell in sheet1.col(3):
  sum[int(cell.value)] += 1
```

But, the `cell.value` may not be converted `int` (integer value) and you need exception control block

```python
# create dictionary sem = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}
sem = {x: 0 for x in range(1,7)}

for cell in sheet1.col(3):
    try:
        sum[int(cell.value)] += 1
    except ValueError:
        print('Error value in cell {}'.format(cell.value))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.    Tried the type conversion. Results in following error. `value = int(cell.value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' `                                                               Please note the input file has this warning [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kbx5.png)